# How to style category output

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach, categories

I got a little help from somebody and have been using the following to diplay my category titles under each post (magazine style wordpress blog). It also excludes a category which the theme relys on (every post must be part of this cat to be displayed on the front page).

```php
<?php
    // For each of the categories, create them as category variables
    foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) {
        // If the category is NOT the cat_name (category name) then echo some stuff
        // So grab all... except where they match cat_name (exclude basically)
        if ($category->cat_name != 'Featured') {
            echo '<a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a> ';
        }
    }
?>
```

However, I would like to style each displayed category title ie;

From this

`Movie Music TV Funny`

To this

`[Movies] [Music] [TV] [Funny]`

Is this easily done? Can able point me in the right direction?

Comment: You can accept an answers, right? If yes, can you accept please, so this question will be finished.

Answer (score 2):

Just modify this line:

```
echo '<a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>&#91;' . $category->name.'&#93;</a> '; 
//added &#91; = [ and &#93; = ]
```

Comment: Damn you guys are seriously fast. Awesome, I would never had gotten that. Thanks so much for helping me...works a treat. Its a strange request, but I think it looks nicer! I cant vote up (i dont have enough rep points yet)

Answer (score 1):

```
echo '<a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>[' . $category->name.']</a> ';
```

Comment: Hi Vlad, I cant vote up (still a noob haha)...but thanks for taking time to help me. I can see there is differences in your code from Shoguns, Im using his only because I seen his reply first. Cheers man, appreicated :)